# Using FFMPEG in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am trying to strip audio from a video file using FFMPEG in C#. I know what the code is for doing such an operation (as far as I know) but I am not 100% sure where I need to keep the `ffmpeg.exe` file in my project and how to access it.

My code so far is as follows:

```
public void stripAudioTest(string videoFilename, ExportProgressWindow callback, string destinationAudioFile)
{
    string FFMPEG_PATH = "*************"; //not sure what to put here?????
    string strParam = " -i " + videoFileName + " -ab 160k -ar 44100 -f wav -vn " +   destinationAudioFile;
    process(FFMPEG_PATH, strParam);
    callback.Increment(100); 
}

public void process(string Path_FFMPEG, string strParam)
{
    try
    {
        Process ffmpeg = new Process();
        
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = Path_FFMPEG;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = strParam;
        ffmpeg.Start();
        ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Anything helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can use any absolute or relative path you want.

But I would advice against a relative path, just in case the 'Current Directory' changes.

Under WinForms you can use the ExecutablePath and put the exe in your own Bin folder.

```
 // winforms
 string FFMPEG_PATH = Path.Combine(
      Path.GetDirectoryName( Application.ExecutablePath), 
      "ffmpeg.exe");
```

For a Console App I couldn't find such an easy way to get the Exe path.

Comment: [`Application.ExecutablePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx) returns "_the path for the executable file that started the application, including the executable name._" So this will return something like `...\bin\MyApp.EXE\ffmpeg.exe` which won't be valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ffmpeg.exe directory to your solution. Set its `Build Action` to `Content` and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always` like so:

[image]

Now this will ensure it exists in your bin directory alongside your executable. You could then modify your method like so:

```
    public void stripAudioTest(string videoFilename, ExportProgressWindow callback, string destinationAudioFile)
    {
        var appDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        var FFMPEG_PATH = Path.Combine(appDirectory, "ffmpeg.exe");
        if (!File.Exists(FFMPEG_PATH))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot find ffmpeg.exe.");
            return;
        }

        string strParam = " -i " + videoFilename + " -ab 160k -ar 44100 -f wav -vn " + destinationAudioFile;
        process(FFMPEG_PATH, strParam);
        callback.Increment(100);
    }
```